# VBA code to Highlight duplicate columns in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a VBA to validate the contents of an excel sheet. I want unique values in the first column, and to be able to determine the validity of these values using the foreign keys on another column. This is what I have to validate for unique entries:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Application.CountIf(Range("A:A"), Target) > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Duplicate Data", vbCritical, "Remove Data"
        Target.Value = ""
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

It prevents duplicate entry in the first row. But what I really want is to be able to detect duplicate by running the macros on an already filled spreadsheet, and to have invalid fields highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Sub sbHighlightDuplicatesInColumn()
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim matchFoundIndex As Long
Dim iCntr As Long

lastCol = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
For iCntr = 1 To lastCol
    If Cells(1, iCntr) <> "" Then
        matchFoundIndex = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(1, iCntr), Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, iCntr)), 0)
        If iCntr <> matchFoundIndex Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, iCntr).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome!. It worked. Thanks @VBA_SQL_Programmer for your time and effort. Really grateful

Comment: No problem at all.  I am glad it worked out for you.

Comment: could you help with the question  I posted here?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42451868/setting-foreign-keys-constraint-in-excel-using-vba